# Get The Value Of Consecutive Cells In VBA

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I have this code in which I get values from an Excel sheet and display a result according to the condition.

In my second `if`statement I want to check whether `ocell.value < sd11` .

After checking that I need to check the next five consecutive values either they are equal or not. If yes then show the result.

Can anyone tell me how to get the cell values of next five consecutive terms? What I thought I have mentioned in the code but its not working.

```
 Sub DoStuff()
   Dim oCell As Range
   sd11 = Range("s11")

   For Each oCell In Range("e4:e48")
       If oCell.Value < sd13 Then
            Range("R2").Value = "Rule 1s voilation"
            End If

        If oCell.Value < sd11 And oCell.Value = oCell.Value + 1 And oCell.Value = oCell.Value + 2 And oCell.Value = oCell.Value + 3 And oCell.Value = oCell.Value + 4 Then
           Range("T5").Value = "Rule 4s voilation"
          End If

   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Change all the "And"'s to "Or"...  but wait, how can a value be equal to itself plus 1? What do you mean by "get the cell values of next five consecutive terms?" You mean, check oCell against the 5 cells  below it, by row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
If oCell.Value < sd11 And oCell.Value = oCell.Value + 1 And oCell.Value = oCell.Value + 2 And oCell.Value = oCell.Value + 3 And oCell.Value = oCell.Value + 4 Then
      Range("T5").Value = "Rule 4s voilation"
End If
```

given a oCell.Value of 6 and sd11 value of 11 , you are essentially asking

```
If 6 < 11 And 6 = 7 And 6 = 8 And 6 = 9 And 6 = 10 Then
    Range("T5").Value = "Rule 4s voilation"
End If
```

because the Value property of a Range (Cell) returns the value associated with that cell.

Since that kind of logic is non-sense and I think the error is with the way you understand how to work with Excel objects in VBA, given the fact that you are new to VBA, I will assume you are trying to see if the value in any of the 5 rows directly below oCell are equivalent to oCell. This can be done by referring the cells themselves by using the offset feature, like so.

```
' i used Or because I thought it might be more what you want. Change to AND if you require all 5 cells to be equal to oCell
    If oCell.Value < sd11 Then
        If oCell.Value = oCell.Offset(1).Value Or oCell.Value = oCell.Offset(2).Value Or oCell.Value = oCell.Offset(3).Value or oCell.Value = oCell.Offset(4).Value or oCell.Value = oCell.Offset(5).Value Then
            Range("T5").Value = "Rule 4s voilation"
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it scientifically:

`if WorksheetFunction.AveDev(oCell.Resize(5)) = 0 then` ...